# laravel preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to save data in my database but I get error in my output after it store the data can some one help me 
I am trying to save the data and not out put some error but her after it save the data it send error saying preg_replace what can I do to stop it and redirect to other route

here is my controller

```
public function create()
{

return view('employmentform');
}

public function handleCreate(Request $request)
{




 $employe = employe::create([
            'fname' => $request->input('first_name'),
            'lname' => $request->input('last_name'),
            'phone' => $request->input('phone_number'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'houseno' => $request->input('house'),
            'kebele' => $request->input('kebele'),
            'city' => $request->input('city'),
            'state' => $request->input('state'),
            'age' => $request->input('date'),
            'username' => $request->input('user_name'),
            'sex' => $request->input('sex'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('country')),
            'salary' => $request->input('salary'),
            'bankaccount' => $request->input('account'),
            'bankname' => $request->input('bank'),
           'employedate' => getdate(),
           'contactid'=> 1,

        ]);

return Redirect::action('ContactController@create');;

}
```

her is my  form view

```
<form action="{{ action('EmployeController@handleCreate') }}" method="post" role="form">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<label for="first_name" id="first_name" >first name</label>
<input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="last_name" id="last_name">last name</label>
<input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="date" id="date">day of birth</label>
<input name="date" type="date" id="date" class="form-control"></br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"/>Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"/>Female</br>
<label for="phone_number" id="phone_number">phone_number</label>
<input name="phone_number" type="text" id="phone_number" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="email" id="email">email</label>
<input name="email" type="email" id="email" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="house" id="house">house_number</label>
<input name="house" type="text" id="house" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="kebele" id="kebele">kebele</label>
<input name="kebele" type="text" id="kebele" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="city" id="city">city</label>
<input name="city" type="text" id="city" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="state" id="state">state</label>
<input name="state" type="text" id="state" class="form-control"></br>

<label for="user_name" id="user_name">user_name</label>
<input name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="password" id="password">password</label>
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control"></br>
<label  >re-password</label>
<input name="password_confirmation"type="password"  class="form-control"></br>
<label for="work" id="work">work position</label>
<input name="work" type="text" id="work" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="salary" id="salary">salary</label>
<input name="salary" type="text" id="salary" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="account" id="account">bank account number</label>
<input name="account" type="text" id="account" class="form-control"></br>
<label for="bank" id="bank">bank name</label>
<input name="bank" type="text" id="bank" class="form-control"></br>

<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />

    </form>
```

it store the data in the data base but send error

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 686:
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

`enter code here`

Comment: show us helpers.php line 686 to help you debugging

Comment: The helpers.php file can be found here: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php. I'm not sure what's calling that method but I think your issue is possibly here: `return Redirect::action('ContactController@create');;` firstly remove the double semi colon if that is in your code and try doing this instead to see if it has an effect: `return redirect()->action('App\Http\Controllers\ContactController@create');` or whatever the path to your controller is.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and it turned out to be caused by having a 2+ levels nested array (**not JSON serialized**) inside my POST data.

If you have a pattern like this in the headers of your POST request (use Chrome's inspector to look), then you have the same problem, and you need to remove or serialize to JSON the contents of your array (`data[pivot]` in my example):

```
_method:PUT
data[id]:6
data[site_id]:1
data[name]:sdafasfvdsfdsfg
data[url]:
data[created_at]:2015-09-04 12:51:54
data[updated_at]:2015-09-04 12:51:54
data[pic]:
data[original_pic]:

// ! This was the problem:
data[pivot][quiz_id]:1
data[pivot][product_id]:6
```

Hope it helps!

PS. For any core Laravel developers reading this: *please find a way to improve error reporting in general, some errors are really "WTF" and almost impossible to trace without trial-an-error.*